# assign to base component of a derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

How can i assign a base class instance to the base class "member" of a derived class from the derived class?

```
class A{
public:
   A();
   A(const A& i);
   A &operator =(const A& i);
   ~A();
};

class B: public A{
public:
  void f(){
    A a;
    // calc(a);
    *this = a; // <- how?
  }
  void x(){};
private:
  int i;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple solution is to use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast):

```
dynamic_cast<A &>(*this) = a;
```

Answer (score 1):

another obvious way (how could i miss this at the first place??) is to directly call the assignment operator of the base class:

```
A::operator=(a);
```